# _save_after triggered before saving the product data in database

Tags: magento-1.7, create-order, create-product

**Intro**: I'm a Python(Django) developer who is working at a company where
we use Magento in the backend to sell products on our website. I'm not
really experienced in Magento. We are using `Magento version 1.7.0.2`.

**What I want**: On certain events like new product/order/customer create, I
want Magento to do some functions. *Eg: For new product create, I want
magento to call a celery task which will check certain conditions and
send an email to the site merchandiser if some data is wrong.*

**What I have done**: As far as I understand, Magento has an event like
`_save_after` which is triggered after a new product is saved. Using
this, Magento is calling the celery task with the `entity_id` of the
product on this even trigger. When the celery task is triggered, I'm
querying the database(`catalog_product_entity` table) for the product using the `entity_id` sent from
Magento.

**Issue**: In some cases, when I'm querying the database for the newly
created product, the database returns 0 rows. This happens almost all
the time.

**What I think**: I think, there might be some sort of asynchronous queueing
done in Magento which is causing this issue. Can someone give me an
explanation to this and let me know how to fix this issue?

I've searched a lot about this and still not able to figure what caused
this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **What I think:** I think, there might be some sort of asynchronous queueing done in Magento which is causing this issue. Can someone give me an explanation to this and let me know how to fix this issue?

You are on the wrong track here. What happens: The product is saved within a transaction. To do something after the change has been commited to the database, you can use the `catalog_product_save_commit_after` event instead of `catalog_product_save_after`.

But just to fetch the ID it should not be necessary, because Magento already retrieves the inserted ID and assigns it to the object (see [Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract::save()](https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/magento-1.7/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Db/Abstract.php#L455))

So in the observer for `catalog_product_save_after`, you can retrieve it:

```
$observer->getProduct()->getId()
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This explains a lot. Now I understand that what I need is the `_save_commit_after` event.